# COBOL-Record is being replaced instead of added

Tags: if-statement, output, cobol

my program is suppose to add record to the output file if JOBCODE = S and SALES > 100,000.00. The variables are all being passed properly but when the program is finished only the last record remains in the output file and I can't figure out why. How do I add it under neath the previous record? I have also used OPEN EXTEND already and received the same result. This is what the output currently looks like:

```
Employee recognition for the week ending: 2022-06-22
----------------------------------------------------
Last Name             First Name          Store #
----------------------------------------------------
ESTERA                BETHANY               0003
```

It should be:

```
Employee recognition for the week ending: 2022-06-22
----------------------------------------------------
Last Name             First Name          Store #
----------------------------------------------------
CAMERON               STANLEY               0003
ELDOUR                JOHNATHAN             0002
KENT                  LORENE                0001
NGUYEN                CARMELO               0002
SRIVASTAVA            SAM                   0003
LABRIE                ARMAND                0003
CHU                   LARISA                0001
FORLINI               COREEN                0002
ESTERA                BETHANY               0003
```

Here is my program:

```
  program-id. Assignment6 AS "Assignment6".
 environment division.
   input-output section.
  *INPUT FILE DECLARATION
    SELECT IN-FILE ASSIGN "C:\DataFiles\dataIn.dat"
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
  *SALES RECONGNITION OUTPUT FILE DECLARATION       
   SELECT OUT-FILE-SALES ASSIGN 
       "C:\DataFiles\SalespersonRecongnition.rpt"
            ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
  *SALARY EXPENSES OUTPUT FILE DECLARATION

   configuration section.

   data division.
   file section.
   
   FD IN-FILE.
   01 IN-RECORD.
     03 IN-EMPLOYEEID PIC X(4).
     03 IN-JOBCODE PIC X(1).
     03 IN-LASTNAME PIC X(14).
     03 IN-FIRSTNAME PIC X(14).
     03 IN-STARTDATE PIC 9(8).
     03 IN-STORENUM PIC 9(4).
     03 IN-SALARY PIC 9(6).
     03 IN-SALES PIC 9(8).
     
   FD OUT-FILE-SALES.
   01 SALES-OUT-RECORD PIC X(52).

   
   working-storage section.
  *END OF FILE 
   01 WS-EOF PIC 9(1) VALUE 0.
   
  *WS IN-RECORD HOLDER
   01 WS-IN-RECORD.
     03 WS-IN-EMPLOYEEID PIC X(4).
     03 WS-IN-JOBCODE PIC X(1).
     03 WS-IN-LASTNAME PIC X(14).
     03 WS-IN-FIRSTNAME PIC X(14).
     03 WS-IN-STARTDATE PIC 9(8).
     03 WS-IN-STORENUM PIC 9(4).
     03 WS-IN-SALARY PIC 9(6).
     03 WS-IN-SALES PIC 9(8).
     
  *SALES REPORT HEADINGS STRUCTURE
   01 SALES-RECORD-HEADING1.
     03 FILLER PIC A(52) VALUE 
     "Employee recognition for the week ending: 2022-06-22".
   01 SALES-RECORD-FILLER1.
     03 FILLER PIC X(52) VALUE ALL '-'.
   01 SALES-RECORD-HEADING2.
     03 FILLER PIC X(9) VALUE "Last Name".
     03 FILLER PIC X(13) VALUE SPACE.
     03 FILLER PIC X(10) VALUE "First Name".
     03 FILLER PIC X(10) VALUE SPACE.
     03 FILLER PIC X(7) VALUE "Store #".
     03 FILLER PIC X(3) VALUE SPACE.
   01 SALES-RECORD-FILLER2.
     03 FILLER PIC X(52) VALUE ALL "-".

  *SALES RECORD ROW STRUCTURE
   01 SALES-ROW.
     03 WS-SALES-LASTNAME PIC X(14).
     03 FILLER PIC X(8) VALUE SPACE.
     03 WS-SALES-FIRSTNAME PIC X(14).
     03 FILLER PIC X(8) VALUE SPACE.
     03 WS-SALES-STORENUM PIC 9(4).
     03 FILLER PIC X(4) VALUE SPACE.
     
   procedure division.
       
       
  *MAIN PROGRAM 
 
   PERFORM OPEN-FILES.
   PERFORM READ-FILE
       UNTIL WS-EOF = 1.
   PERFORM CLOSE-FILES.
     
       
   OPEN-FILES.
       OPEN INPUT IN-FILE
         OUTPUT OUT-FILE-SALES
         WRITE SALES-OUT-RECORD FROM SALES-RECORD-HEADING1
         WRITE SALES-OUT-RECORD FROM SALES-RECORD-FILLER1
         WRITE SALES-OUT-RECORD FROM SALES-RECORD-HEADING2
         WRITE SALES-OUT-RECORD FROM SALES-RECORD-FILLER2.
               
       
   READ-FILE.
         READ IN-FILE INTO IN-RECORD
             AT END
                SET WS-EOF TO 1
             NOT AT END
                    PERFORM GOT-A-RECORD
                       END-READ.

   GOT-A-RECORD.
   MOVE IN-EMPLOYEEID TO WS-IN-EMPLOYEEID
   MOVE IN-JOBCODE    TO WS-IN-JOBCODE
   MOVE IN-LASTNAME   TO WS-IN-LASTNAME
   MOVE IN-FIRSTNAME  TO WS-IN-FIRSTNAME
   MOVE IN-STARTDATE  TO WS-IN-STARTDATE
   MOVE IN-STORENUM   TO WS-IN-STORENUM
   MOVE IN-SALARY     TO WS-IN-SALARY
   MOVE IN-SALES      TO WS-IN-SALES
   
   PERFORM SALES-REPORT-ADD-RECORD.
   
   
   SALES-REPORT-ADD-RECORD.
       IF WS-IN-JOBCODE = "S"
           AND WS-IN-SALES > 10000000
               MOVE WS-IN-LASTNAME TO WS-SALES-LASTNAME
               MOVE WS-IN-FIRSTNAME TO WS-SALES-FIRSTNAME
               MOVE WS-IN-STORENUM TO WS-SALES-STORENUM
               PERFORM WRITE-RECORD
       END-IF .
      

   WRITE-RECORD.
       WRITE SALES-OUT-RECORD FROM SALES-ROW
       DISPLAY SALES-ROW.
       
   CLOSE-FILES.
       CLOSE IN-FILE
               OUT-FILE-SALES.
            
       
 .
        
   end program Assignment6.
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has no explicit end, therefore it "falls through":
You likely want to add `GOBACK.` at the end of your main.

Comment: it says I don't have enough reputation to vote? but I will as soon as I can!

Comment: I believe I did it, the check mark?

Comment: Yes, the distinction is "a check mark says: that helped the OP best" (can also only be set by the OP), an upvote is possible from everyone and about "useful answer/question" (for the later also: self-contained, shows research effort); if you get multiple answers those often are useful and therefore "should be voted", but they may not "work for you".
A question not-yet-marked as answered gets less views from people that search for answers and more views from people that want to answer (kind of "open").